# Unable to pass the street signs reCaptcha

Tags: support, login, captcha, recaptcha

Ok, I cannot for the life of me get past this captca. I select all the street signs, who knows whether they're right.

But also, if you're supposed to select images, what's with the text box below? there's no instruction on what to type there.

[image: Street signs reCaptcha]

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? Do you have any blocking extensions such as AdBlock or Disconnect enabled?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 and I'm on the newest version of Chrome. The tech guy put Avast on my computer a couple of weeks ago, would that cause this?

Comment: It's very possible. We tend to see these oddities with the reCaptcha system when calls back to Google's servers are being blocked at some point, and the script can't function properly. I've also experienced this issue on PlayStation's built-in browser, which simply doesn't work and will always say the answers you chose were incorrect no matter what you choose.